# How to extract some of the items in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to extract some of the items from an object. If I'm not wrong, I need to use for...in to loop the object items.

```js
let myObject = {
  id: 1,
  company: "Apple",
  product: {
    name: "iPhone",
    price: "100",
    releaseDate: "01 Jan 2019",
    color: {
      black: "#000000",
      silver: "#C0C0C0",
    }
  }
}
for (property in myObject) {
  console.log(`${property} = ${myObject[property]}`);
}
```

How can I only get the `product`'s `name` and `price` only?

Expected result:

```
newArray = [
    name: "iPhone",
    price: 100,
]
```

Comment: your expected output syntax as well as input is invalid. Also will you have a single product object or many

Comment: you myObject is not a valid object

Comment: your example object also invalid

Answer (score 2):

What you need is just [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let myObject = {
  id: 1,
  company: "Apple",
  product: {
    name: "iPhone",
    price: "100",
    releaseDate: "01 Jan 2019",
    color: {
      black: "#000000",
      silver: "#C0C0C0",
    }
  }
}


const {name, price} = myObject.product

console.log({name, price})
```

In case myObject is an array of object like @Hasan Sh mentioned. You can use `reduce`

```js
let myObject = [
  {
  id: 1,
  company: "Apple",
  product: {
    name: "iPhone",
    price: "100",
    releaseDate: "01 Jan 2019",
    color: {
      black: "#000000",
      silver: "#C0C0C0",
    }
  }
},
{
  id: 2,
  company: "Samsung",
  product: {
    name: "galaxy S9",
    price: "100",
    releaseDate: "01 Jan 2019",
    color: {
      black: "#000000",
      silver: "#C0C0C0",
    }
  }
}

]

const rs = myObject.reduce((acc, e) => {
  const {name, price} = e.product
  acc.push({name, price})
  return acc
}, [])




console.log(rs)
```

Comment: OR const {product:{name, price}} = myObject

Comment: I think what he meant is that the `myObject` is an object within an array?! 
`e.g. const data = [myObject, ...];`
In that case loop through the `data` array and do TamDc's solution.